# SSAS DSV Update

Tags: ssas-2008

My development environment at work is not sufficient to process ALL of the data in my cube. It continually brings down my dev box. I have open tickets within my own IT so I am not asking about that.

I have add filters in my DSV to limit how much data is processed, but now I only want to update the metadata within my cube so the next time I process the cube it uses the new DSV defintion.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, in the DSV right click in the white space and choose refresh. See a blog [here](http://www.msbiguide.com/2011/12/22/refresh-option-in-ssas-dsv/) where I found the solution.